# Low city water pressure booster - when would it turn on?

Tags: plumbing, water-pressure

If I were to install a pressure booster pump, would it work / be on consistently or is it only triggered by specific water pressure ranges?  A plumber told me it would only kick on if the pressure dropped below 30 or 40 psi, but the documentation I'm finding about different pumps doesn't indicate that that is the case.

Comment: If you add a booster and pressure tank the pressure can be set to what you want it to be. If you always want 60 psi pressure the turn on pressure would be set for 60 or slightly higher. The turn off pressure would be higher 80-90 psi range so the pump would cycle on until the set point is made then turn off until the pressure drops below the turn on set point.

Comment: The booster should always turn off when the desired output pressure is reached.  Sort of like any well pump + pressure reservoir system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on who engineers the pump and controls. They can be either way. The most economical way would be with an expansion tank and a pump that runs only on demand. I have seen both systems, and installed both types.

Comment: Thanks!  Our township's city water has pretty poor water pressure (exact psi not known), I'm hoping to install one of these systems in my house to make it more livable.  Any recommendations / caveats (aside from "hire a plumber", which I'm planning to do)?

Comment: GOOGLE    " Domestic water 101" and PlumbingSupply.com as a start point